# R Conditional Column Type Change

Tags: r

I have a dataset "train" that consists of 59 columns. I'm trying to change the column types conditionally, based on a ending substring of the column name. I first define the function, then use apply. The result I get is that all the variables are erased, and countless warnings of the following are shown:

In if (stri_sub(var, -3, -1) == "cat") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I can't figure out what's wrong with the function, but I'm guessing that's where the problem is since the apply line was given as an approach in another question. What am I doing wrong?

```
name_change <- function(var){
if (stri_sub(var, -3,-1) == "cat")
{train[,var] <- as.factor(train[,var])}
#else do nothing
}

train[,names(train)] = apply(train[,names(train)], 2,name_change)
```

Comment: `if` is not a vectorised function and so "only the first element will be used" in the comparison. `sel <- stri_sub(names(train), -3,-1) == "cat"; train[,sel] <- lapply(train[,sel], as.factor)` or something similar is what you want.

Comment: Ah, a true/false assignment. Clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a correction of your approach, 100% base `R`.

```
name_change <- function(var,col){
  suffix <- "Length"
  if (substr(var,nchar(var)-nchar(suffix)+1,nchar(var)) == suffix)
    {col <- as.integer(col)}
  col
}

iris2 <- data.frame(Map(name_change,names(iris),iris),stringsAsFactors = F)
str(iris2)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#   $ Sepal.Length: int  5 4 4 4 5 5 4 5 4 4 ...
# $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
# $ Petal.Length: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

In particular:

- don't use `apply` with margin = 2 on `data.frames`, it's converting them to `matrix` and is not efficient.
- You can use `lapply` to loop on `data.frame` columns, but here you need to loop on `names` as well, so you need `Map`.
- Map returns a list so I'm converting it back to a `data.frame`
- Pay attention to the fact that i'm explicitely returning the column, modified or not, from the `name_change` function.

Answer (score 1):

Can easily be done with `dplyr`. Here's how to change the `Sepal.Length` and `Petal.Length` columns from `dbl` into `int`.

```
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

glimpse(iris, 60)

Observations: 150
Variables: 5
$ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6,...
$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4,...
$ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4,...
$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3,...
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, se...

iris %<>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Length")), as.integer) %>% 
    glimpse(60)

Observations: 150
Variables: 5
$ Sepal.Length <int> 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4...
$ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4,...
$ Petal.Length <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
$ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3,...
$ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, se...
```

Comment: Very nice! What does glimpse(60) do? I'd still like to see a "base" solution using the standard function/apply method, just to be a better programmer.

Comment: though `stri_sub` is from `stringi`, not base ;)

Comment: `glimpse(data, 60)` means, "Print a preview of `data` with one column per line, but limit the line length to 60 characters only." Limiting the char length is useful for printing out on paper, or not overwhelming people on Stack Overflow!